# MySQL query several records from certain date range

Tags: mysql

here's my recordset:

```
id   date
-----------------------
1    2017-01-11
2    2017-01-12
3    2017-01-14
4    2017-01-15
4    2017-01-16
```

i'd like to query all records within the date range 2017-01-14 to 2017-01-16

currently i'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (date='2017-01-14' OR date='2017-01-15' OR date='2017-01-16')
```

is there a better way (which would be probably faster for bigger ranges)?
thanks

PS: i'm aware i could use:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE date >= '2017-01-14' AND date <= '2017-01-16'
```

but the problem is that i don't want "gaps" between each day.

Comment: use between **SELECT ... WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-14' AND '2017-01-17';**

Comment: Gaps? What sort of gaps?

Comment: i mean as shown in my data: there's 11,12,13 (is missing), 14, ..
so the query would be incorrect

Comment: I'm not following. You're not even querying for 13. And what would be incorrect?

Comment: sorry, more specific: i want to query all record-"sets" eg. between 2017-01-12 and 2017-01-15 with ALL dates set (12,13,14,15) which should return 4 records, but as 13 is missing it will only return 3. so the query also needs to consider the amount of records i guess (using datediff?)

Comment: Yuor problem isn't with selecting the date range, your problem is with adding the missing dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM foo
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-01-14' AND '2017-01-16';
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem of the missing date `2017-01-13`?

Comment: @Barmar This was in response to the original question, which mentioned nothing about gaps. Furthermore, it's fully equivalent to the original query, which was implied to be functionally correct.

Comment: It's not my question. I'd like to remove my downvote, but I can't unless you edit the answer. But maybe you should just delete it, since the question was edited and it's no longer useful.